# How to perform multiple queries in a hook (FeathersJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I have a few documents of users in my mongoDB. Each user has a field duties which is an array.

For example:

User 1:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a943dd87d08c3c91b0a36c9"),
  "name" : "Kate Rose",
  "duties": []
}
```

User 2:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a16bfacb7a982bc9b7bd7f9"),
  "name" : "Albert Saxon",
  "duties": []
}
```

I try to do a series of queries using loop in hook feathersjs with mongoose like shown below:

```
patch: [
    function(context){

    var array = [
      { _id: '5a943dd87d08c3c91b0a36c9',    <-- ID of user 1
        data: {                             <-- data to update there duties array
         group: 1,
         comment: 'comment one',
         date: '2018-03-05T00:00:00.000Z'
        }
      },
     { _id: '5a16bfacb7a982bc9b7bd7f9',     <-- ID of user 2
       data: {
         group: 0,
         comment: 'comment two',
         date: '2018-03-05T00:00:00.000Z'
        }
      }
    ]

    var _id = "5a943dd87d08c3c91b0a36c9";

    for(var rowData of array) {

       var userId = rowData._id;
       var data = rowData.data;

       var query = { _id: userId, "duties._id": _id }

       /*
        * I try update selected object in duties array by _id using
        * positional operator and userId
        */

       context.app.service('parents').patch(null, { $set: { "duties.$.comment": data.comment, "duties.$.group": data.group } }, { query }, (error, result) => {

         if(result.length==0){

            /*
             * If result == 0 a new object is added
             */

            context.app.service('parents').update({_id: userId}, { $push: { duties: { _id: _id, date: data.date, comment: data.comment, group: data.group, status: 1 }}}, { query }, (error, result) => {

            });

         }

       });

    }

}]
```

As look above I need update duties fileds each users from the array but in my case after run my function in result I receive updated one user and in there duties filed are the same two objects (duplicate) as if two queries update the same user. What is wrong?

*** I resolved my problem**

I added Promise to my loop and now it's works excellent

```
for(var rowData of array) {

   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

   var userId = rowData._id;
   var data = rowData.data;

   var query = { _id: userId, "duties._id": _id }

   context.app.service('parents').patch(null, { $set: { "duties.$.comment": data.comment, "duties.$.group": data.group } }, { query }, (error, result) => {

      if(result.length==0){

         context.app.service('parents').update({_id: userId},
                 { $push: { duties: { _id: _id, date: data.date, comment: data.comment, group: data.group, status: 1 }}},
                 { query });

      }

   });

   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first `.patch` and call the `context.app.service('parents').update(...)` by itself.

Does it add what you want to the `duties` array? What does the resulting data structure look like?

Comment: I can't remove .patch method because I update in this way duties fields each user by positional operator. I need update objects in duties array there users where _id. Only patch method it's doing. So if result == 0, if _id not exist in there array then .update method push new object. I think this solutions is for me. Maybe I should using promise that each users to get new object?

Comment: I checked your solution. It's work but I need .patch method because as I mentioned earlier if object exists in array, it must be updated. .Update method only create (push) if object not exists.I think that my problem is in query object. In this object _id filed is always last element of array therefore only one user duties array is updated, in this way created is new object (duplicate)

Comment: I updated my question. I resolved my problem. Please, tell my why it's works? I think that without a Promise the loop continued itself work before a .patch method return result that's why only a duties array of one user has updated, but I'm not sure. It'm right? Now if my array contains two elements, and one user has in her duties this element, this element is updates but in the duties array of the second user the second element of array is adds if not exists (push). In other case it is also updated. Greats!

Comment: Oh interesting, the issue of the Promise and not waiting for the first result makes sense. I think you figured it out!